# Include maven dependencies in eclipse "Run As -> Android Application" build

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I develop an Android App using eclipse, the [Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) and the [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).

Building and installing the application on the commandline (`mvn install` / `adb install`) works fine - especially it includes all dependencies specified in the pom.xml.

Deploying the application to Android via eclipse (Run as -> Android Application) does not automatically put the dependencies in the apk file - although specified in the pom.xml. I haven to explicit declare them in the eclipse project `Build Path -> Libraries` dialog.

Is there a way to make eclipse include the dependencies defined in the *pom.xml* without definig them twice in the project *Build-Path -> Libraries*?

**EDIT:** To clarify - the eclipse project includes a "Maven Dependencies" entry with all dependencies specified in the pom.xml. But these dependencies will not be included in the apk during install via "Run As -> Android Application". To include them, each one has to be extra added in the "Java Build Path -> Libraries" dialog. That's the pain!

Comment: sounds like a bug or missing feature in the plugin, maven knows how to deal with it but the project under the eclipse doesn't. can you do a "maven" import to eclipse, that is open file->import->maven project or something of that sort and then it might update the build path automatically ?

Comment: @codeScriber The maven import works fine. All Dependencies appear within the "Maven Dependencies" entry - so developping is not the problem. But they will not get installed with the app (to the emulator) unless every dependend jar is explicitly added (Add External JARs...) to the Libraries tab in the Java Build Path dialog.

Comment: @K.Claszen True that. as soon as I added facebook lib as external jar everything started to work.
However, have you figured out how to fix this in more "normal" way? I mean it's kinda killing the point of having Maven if you have to add your libs manually.

Comment: @Mike Bevz I have not found any other way so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at [m2e-android](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/), assuming you are already using [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/).

Comment: Sounds really good! Will try it tomorrow and give feedback (time is running out today). Thanks!

Comment: Did you make any goog experience with this plugin. After installation eclipse is hanging in "Building Workspace..." very often (at least when "Build automatically" is enabled) and also the build process seems to loop. The worst thing is that dependencies are not included in the apk file as expected.

Comment: I would like to mark this as the correct answer but as the plugin does not include all project depdencencies in the apk file and it also slows down the eclipse "Automaticall Build" I can not recommend it for now (assumed that I did not make any mistakes).

Comment: Check out the latest version. These issues are both fixed.

Comment: I did a fresh install of 0.2.5 (this is what I get from the update site). Problems first still remained but than I detected a `Cannot add source folder Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK` error during build. I changed the eclipse `Default output folder` to be NOT `<project>/target/classes` (instead `bin`) and now it works (dependencies are included). Still very beasy on each code change when `build automatically` is enabled. Seems to build complete apk file which is only necessary in case of device deployment in my opinion. Nevertheless now very useful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I enabled the "Maven Dependencies"-checkmark at "Order and Export" within projects "Java Build Path" configuration and that seems to include all maven dependencies.

These dependencies (compile scope) are put into target/android-classes (and there are a lot of them, most commonly snapshots of internal projects, about 10). I had some other difficulties but that probably is related to the m2eclipse android integration plugin (at least on windows 7).

To get my properly set up maven project running I had to:

either import as maven project or...

clean previously created eclipse files (mvn eclipse:clean, mvn eclipse:eclipse), then enable maven dependecy resolution for that project, adept Java Build Path (gen -> target/android-classes, src -> target/classes, default output folder -> android-classes) and export Maven Dependencies (enable checkmark).

One thing i stumbled upon was this "Could not find *.apk!" error when running or debugging the android application. I could fix that by using a 32bit jdk for the used execution environment.

Comment: What do you mean by _seems to include_? Did you check it? As I observed this does not include 'real' third party libraries. (I do not speak of all the 'provided' transitive dependencies of the com.google.android:android artifact).