# Android and maven: problem with maven dependencies in apk

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, apk

I'm currently working on an Android project using Maven as the build tool. However I'm having a problem with including dependencies, to be more specific: none of the dependencies listed in my pom file are packed in the apk. This results in `ClassDefNotFound` errors when I'm trying to run the app on my emulator (the underlying `ClassNotFound` exception is thrown in the Dalvik loader).

I'm using Springsource Tool Suite ( 2.5.2.SR1), with the following plugin configuration:

- Android Development Tools (10.0.1.v201103111512-110841)
- Maven integration for Android Development Tools (0.2.5)
- Maven integration for Eclipse (0.12.1.20110112-1712)
- Maven (2.2.1)

This is my pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>android-test</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>android-test</name>

    <properties> 
        <android-platform>10</android-platform>
        <android-emulator>Android-2.3.3</android-emulator>
        <android-sdk-path>C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk</android-sdk-path>
        <maven-android-plugin-version>2.8.4</maven-android-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <android-version>2.3.1</android-version>
        <spring-android-version>1.0.0.M2</spring-android-version>
        <jackson-version>1.7.2</jackson-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-android-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>${android-platform}</platform>
                        <path>${android-sdk-path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>${android-emulator}</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>false</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-android-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Using Jackson for JSON marshaling -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

And my android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ae.test.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

As far as I can tell, this should be a correct setup. The problem now is, when I try to build this project, I get:

Cannot add source folder Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923555/include-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-run-as-android-application-build) on SO and while the solution (changing the default output folder of eclipse to `bin` instead of `target`) did solve the error, it didn't solve the dependency problem. My generated android files aren't included in the target folder so the solution is of no use to me.

Has anyone else got any experience with setting up Android and Maven and if so, could you please help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you raise a defect for this with the maven-android-plugin project?

https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/entry

Comment: @Ricardo Gladwell - not yet, good point! I'll add it tonight.

Comment: @Ricardo Gladwell - I've managed to get it working, need to retest to see if I can reproduce the bug (built from command line worked). I'll raise a defect if I can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Can you post a link to the issue you created here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I skipped using the Maven integration for Android Development Tools (0.2.5) because the eclipse automatically build process took to long. I could leave my default output folder to `<project>/target/classes` in this case.

Building my project from the command line works fine. The dependencies are included in the apk file.

Running the project from eclipse only works if I add the dependencies explicit to the eclipse project with

```
Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...
```

That was the bitter pill I had to swallow (*I am not native english and hope this sentence makes sence*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also believe it's related to a bug in the maven-android-plugin, but I need to retest it this weekend. If I can reproduce the behaviour, I'll use your answer. I'll update when I know more

Comment: I don not think that it is a bug of the maven-android-plugin as it works well on the command line. This plugin does not claim to work with eclipse. This gap should be closed with the m2eclipse-android-integration plugin - as I understood. Unfortunately this does not work well with eclipse `Build Automatically` feature.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll take this into account when retesting. Expect an update this Saturday.

Comment: I retested it with your setup and get the same result: building it from eclipse doesn't seem to work, but using mvn install android:deploy on your command line works like a charm. Unfortunately, I have no idea whatsoever what's causing the bug.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<scope>compile</scope>` for your dependencies wich are not provided by the target system (e.g. the android libs are provided on android systems) otherwise maven will not put the .class files from your dependencies into the apk.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm currently no longer working with Android (it was a very small POC project), but I will make sure to take your suggestion into account the moment I return to Android programming

Comment: This is it. I added scope compile and that solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use 
`<extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates\>` in `android-maven-plugin` configuration
to remove duplicate jars.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently no longer working on this project, so I can't verify at this time, but this is useful for future reference! On a side note: welcome to Stack Overflow!